# Synonymize [mean] with [meaning]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[mean](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mean) has no wiki and no followers, and looks to be semantically identical to the far-better-established [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). Unfortunately, I can't yet propose synonyms. Someone else able to do the job?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!  But the tag synonym system doesn't scale down very well to sites the size of ELL.  It'd be easier just to replace the tag on all 9 questions, which anyone can do, or ask a moderator like J.R. or Wendikidd to make the synonym.

Comment: @snailboat: Fair enough, although I'm not sure it's the best idea for e.g. me to suggested-edit my way through even 9 questions.

Comment: I could do it, but maybe we should wait for a moderator to synonymize them.  That way it won't bump all 9 questions to the top of the front page :-)

Comment: Nice catch. Done.